# SFML - optimize copying from GPU to RAM

Tags: c++, gpu, sfml

My application contains one short function which copies SFML GPU buffer (`sf::RenderTexture` converted to `sf::Image`) into two-dimensional array of colors (which is stored in RAM and processed by CPU). Here is code:

```
const sf::Image image = renderTexture.getTexture().copyToImage();

for (Point_t y = 0; y < totalHeight; ++y)
{
    for (Point_t x = 0; x < totalWidth; ++x)
    {
        const sf::Color& c = image.getPixel(x, totalHeight - y - 1);
        // here processing this c variable
    }
}
```

The problem is: with screen 256x64px I am getting like 20 FPS - that's too low, I need like 50 FPS in my application. How can I improve performance of this process?

Maybe I should use additional library that would speed it up?

EDIT:

Someone gave suggestion that I should use real imaging library instead of SFML. But the point is that SFML is perfect library for things like rotating objects in real time etc., so I will stick to SFML, just need optimization or another way to copy buffer from GPU to CPU.

Comment: Did you check what is taking the time, the copy call or your processing?

Comment: How frequently you would need to call the code above?

Comment: The copy process is taking this time. I am calling this code in loop every possible time, I need like 50-60 FPS so this code should execute 50-60 times per second, but now it is only 20. Maybe there is another way to do it?

Comment: SFML is no image processing library., If you want to do that, you should look at libraries like **OpenCV**. If you just want to manipulate images on a pixel by pixel basis (like edge detection), you can do so utilizing your SFML's `sf::Shader` class and your GPU for very fast processing. An example can be found in [this almost duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955212/sfml-load-modify-display-bitmap/43956066#43956066).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFML load, modify, display bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955212/sfml-load-modify-display-bitmap)

Comment: My app needs to render TrueType text, BDF text, shapes, videos, animations, images, even HTML files. What would you prefer in this situation? And of course everything needs to be stored in RAM in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For interested ones, I have found a solution:

Copy from GPU to CPU speedup is provided by this lib: https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-fb-matrix

https://github.com/adafruit/rpi-fb-matrix/blob/master/rpi-fb-matrix.cpp (line 70)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do that, SFML optimize it self all this. You really need an Image cant you just pass through sf::Texture and sf::Sprite ?

Comment: I need color of every pixel, and Texture does not provide this possibility

Comment: It is then the only solution though and it is slow because it generate an new image from each call to `copyToImage()`. SFML does not handle this I think... Maybe you should try another lib, or directly use Xlib (only on unix).